# Angular2 http.post setTimeout

Tags: angular, ionic2, settimeout

I have a ion-range (radio button) and I'm getting the data and pushing it so that I can search that data in mongodb and response it to client.But  whenever user drag it(without leave it immediate) it takes all datas and search n times at mongodb so that its getting slower.What I want to do is put a setTime so that after around 1secound user dropped the button it will send the data , not   instantaneous

**Html**

```
  <ion-range min="0" max="200" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="distance" color="secondary" (ngModelChange)="Change()">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" range-left aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:25px;" range-right aria-hidden="true"></i>

  </ion-range>
```

**TS**

```
Change() {
var data = {
  distance: this.distance,
  lat: this.lat1,
  long: this.long1
}

this.http.post('http://localhost:xxxx/api/xxx', data)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.distanceArray = data;
  })


}
```

I guess between } and ) I need to put setTimeint but I never used it.What is your ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the `ion-range` has a Input Property `debounce` which is

> How long, in milliseconds, to wait to trigger the ionChange event
>   after each change in the range value. Default 0.

[Ionic Range API documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/)

I strongly recommend to use Services instead of making http requests directly from the component.

**Edit**

Use `debounce` with `ionChange` instead of `ngModelChange`

```
<ion-range min="0" max="200" pin="true" debounce="1000" [(ngModel)]="distance" color="secondary" (ionChange)="Change($event)">
.......
</ion-range>
```

Comment: Yes you are right but I guess because of ngModelChange debounce doesnt work It still makes the http.post instantaneous @Shanil Fernando